# sqlite3.OperationalError: near " ": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

vocês sabem o quer dizer esse erro?

**Erro:**

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near “ ”: syntax error
```

**Código:**

```
def alterturma(self):

        bancoturmas = Bancoturmas()
        #try:

        c = bancoturmas.conexao.cursor()

        c.execute("update turmas set codigoturma = '" + self.codigoturma + "', periodo= '" + self.periodo + "', turmacodigodisciplina = '" + self.turmacodigodisciplina + "', turmacpfprofessor = '" + self.turmacpfprofessor + "', lista_cpf_alunos = '" + self.lista_cpf_alunos + "' where idturma = " + self.idturma)


        bancoturmas.conexao.commit()  
        c.close()

        return "Turma atualizada com sucesso!"
        #except:
            #return "Ocorreu um erro na alteração da turma"
```

Comment: Em qual linha está dando o erro?

Comment: No `where idturma` está faltando fechar a aspa simples `'`

Comment: nessa aqui: c.execute("update turmas set codigoturma = '" + self.codigoturma + "', periodo= '" + self.periodo + "', turmacodigodisciplina = '" + self.turmacodigodisciplina + "', turmacpfprofessor = '" + self.turmacpfprofessor + "', lista_cpf_alunos = '" + self.lista_cpf_alunos + "' where idturma = " + self.idturma)

Comment: Tenta ver se era o que falei no último comentário, pode ser que seja só a aspa que não foi fechada.

Comment: Tá certo. vou olhar, obrigada !!

Comment: c.execute("update turmas set codigoturma = '" + self.codigoturma + "', periodo= '" + self.periodo + "', turmacodigodisciplina = '" + self.turmacodigodisciplina + "', turmacpfprofessor = '" + self.turmacpfprofessor + "', lista_cpf_alunos = '" + self.lista_cpf_alunos + "' where idturma = '" + self.idturma)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "'"

Comment: deu esse erro agora....   :(    tá difícil....
    self.c.execute("""
AttributeError: 'Turma' object has no attribute 'c'

Comment: a sua resposta deu esse erro aí :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei reformatar a parte do seu código que está dando erro, pra tornar um pouco menos confuso, é apenas um erro de sintaxe relacionado as aspas, então deve resolver:

```
self.c.execute("""
        UPDATE turmas
          codigoturma = ?,
          periodo = ?,
          turmacodigodisciplina = ?,
          turmacpfprofessor = ?,
          lista_cpf_alunos = ?,
        WHERE idturma = ?
        """, (self.codigoturma, self.periodo,self.turmacodigodisciplina,self.turmacpfprofessor,self.lista_cpf_alunos,self.idturma))
```

Note que esta consulta está usando parametrização (ao invés de interpolação de strings simples como no seu exemplo). Isso possui várias vantagens: Livra você de ter que colocar as aspas certas, impede injeção de código SQL nas variáveis, e tem performance melhor, pois uma vez que a interpolação é feita pelo banco de dados, a consulta compilada pode ser armazenada em cache.

Comment: Talvez seria interessante você explicar como funciona uma [consulta parametrizada](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) e qual a estrutura dos parâmetros que podem ser especificado na instrução SQL, talvez o AP não saiba disso :)

Comment: @gato verdade, vou editar a pergunta adicionando essas informações, estou um pouco ocupado, mas assim que puder reformulo a resposta ;)

Comment: Eu não percebi qual foi a aspas ruins. Só se fosse a de `idturma` e fosse uma variável não numérica